# 10 Balls in a row (4B 4W 2R), with not all balls of any color consecutive

Tags: combinatorics

Let N be the number of ways to arrange four black balls, four white balls, and two red balls in a row, so that for each color, not all the balls of that color are consecutive. (For example, if B, W, and R represent a black, white, and red ball, respectively, then the arrangement WRWWRBBBBW is not allowed, because all the black balls are consecutive.) Find the remainder when N is divided by 1000. Many cases blew my head off.(first all black, then white, then red, then two together-3 cases and then all three together...)

Comment: This is a candidate for inclusion-exclusion. Find the total number of arrangements and the number of elements of the sets where at least one color violates the rule.

Comment: @AlexR: The difficult part is to count the number of ways in which for two colors the balls are consecutive, and for the third color the balls are not consecutive (that's three different cases, and counting each case is a difficult task by itself).

Comment: @barakmanos Not really, see the emerged answer.

Answer (score 11):

We will compute the answer by inclusion exclusion.

The total number of ways to arrange the 10 balls is given by $\frac {10!}{4! 4! 2!} = 3150$. These include arrangements that violate the conditions so we need to remove them.

We first remove the cases where all black are consecutive. To count the number of such arrangements imagine merging all black balls into one segment, so in total we have $\frac {7!}{1! 4! 2!} = 105$ ways of arranging the 4 white balls, the 2 red balls and the black segment. Similarly, work for the case where all white balls or red are consecutive and subtract $105$ and $630$ respectively.

By subtracting the above we double-counted the cases where balls of two or more colors are consecutive at the same time and we need to add them back. First, we need to include back the cases where both the white balls and the black balls are consecutive. These are in total $\frac {4!}{1! 1! 2!} = 12$ cases. We do the same for black and red, and white and red to add $\frac {6!}{4! 1! 1!} = 30$ and $\frac {6!}{ 1! 4! 1!} = 30$ cases respectively.

Finally, we need to subtract the number of ways to arrange balls of all colors consecutively which is exactly $\frac {3!}{ 1! 1! 1!} = 6$ ways. So in total we have $3150 - 105 - 105 - 630 + 12 + 30 + 30 - 6 = 2376 \equiv376\pmod{1000}$

Comment: These are the total number of ways. You have to subtract the ones which don't fulfill the required condition.

Comment: Sorry, my bad... Misread the question initially.

Comment: I've verified everything except for the two "$+30$" up there. +1, assuming you've done that part correctly...

Comment: You might want to change the "$=376(mod1000)$" to "\equiv376\pmod{1000}"... In fact, I will do it for you...